# in order to align genome multi-fasta files, do you ignore the chromosome sections?

Tags: sequence-alignment

I want to test my implementation of Needleman-Wunsch on two fasta files downloaded from https://hgdownload.soe.ucsc.edu/.
However, fasta files on this site are multi-fasta and therefore are split into sections each one belonging to a chromosome.
If I want to align the entire genomes in these files:

- do I just ignore the chromosomal separation inside these files? thus do I stitch the chromosomes of each file into one big chunk?
- or do I align combinations of these chromosomes?

Comment: If the fasta really are chromosomes, there will be one per chomosome. Check this in case the multi-fasta you have is an incomplete sequencing of an organism. There is a bioinformatics site on Stackexchange now at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com

Comment: Chromosomes do not form one continuous genome, so I would suggest creating a separate alignment for each chromosome.

Answer (score 1):

If the fasta really are chromosomes, there will be one per chomosome. Check this in case the multi-fasta you have is an incomplete sequencing of an organism. If incomplete there will be many more fasta. There is a bioinformatics site on Stackexchange now at https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com .You would get better answers there.